# Finding maximum of $ad-bc$ on $S^3$

Tags: optimization, proof-verification

One of my friends asked me to find the maximum of $ad-bc$ given that $a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2=1$ and $a, b, c, d \in \mathbb{R}$.

I came up with the following. Can somebody please tell me if it is a reasonable method?

Let $f(a,b,c,d)=ad-bc$. Since gradient of a function gives the direction of maximum change in the function, the gradient of $f$ at the maximum in $3$-sphere shouldn't have any component along the surface of the $3$-sphere. That is, the gradient at the maximum point is normal to the $3$-sphere.

Suppose $f$ takes its maximum on $S^3$ at $(x,y,z,w)$, then $ \nabla f|_{(x,y,z,w)} =k (x,y,z,w)$, which gives $x=w$, $y=-z$, $k=1$ or $x=-w$, $y=z$, $k=-1$.

Hence,  $f(x,y,z,w)=x^2+y^2$ or $-x^2-y^2$ depending on the two cases. But $(x,y,z,w) \in S^3 \implies (x^2+y^2)=\frac{1}{2}$. Hence, maximum value of $f$ on $S^3$ is $\frac{1}{2}$.

Answer (score 7):

I think your solution is fine, though you could solve it without resorting to [Lagrange multipliers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multipliers).

**Alternative proof:** By AM-GM inequality we have $$ad-bc\leq \vert a\vert\vert d\vert +\vert b\vert \vert c\vert\leq\frac{a^2+d^2}{2}+\frac{b^2+c^2}{2}=\frac{1}{2}.$$ The equality is attained, for instance, at $a=d=\pm\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}$ and $b=-c=\pm\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}$.

Comment: Actually, equality is obtained if and only if $a=d$ and $b=-c$, they don't have to be $\pm \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$.

Comment: @N.S. You're right, but in any case we only need one set of values that maximize the objective.

Answer (score 5):

$$1-2(ad-bc)=(a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2)-2ad+2bc=(a-d)^2+(b+c)^2 \geq 0$$

Thus

$$1 \geq 2(ad-bc) $$

with equality if and only if $a-d=b+c =0$.